# Calculate failure percentage using MQL (Google Cloud Platform)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, monitoring-query-language

Need a little bit of help or advice here.
I guess there is no direct way to calculate the success/failure percentage in GCP for the log based metric so I am trying to use MQL for the first time. I have gone through the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples?_ga=2.38675555.-1908812794.1676628209)

Basically I have a log based metric for my API which I can filter using `HTTP Status Code`. This field can contain values like `2XX` and `5XX`. How do i calculate the failure percentage using this. I am trying to do something like (Total number of 5XX errors divided by Total requests) * 100.

I have done a bit of query but I am stuck here. If someone can guide me that would be very helpful. Many Thanks.

```
fetch l7_lb_rule
| metric logging.googleapis.com/user/my_apis
| { t_0:
    filter (metric.URL
     =~ 'https://example.com/myapi/services/myapi' && metric.STATUS='200')
| align
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [compute ratios](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples#qlx-ratios) to display the ratio of requests that return HTTP 500 responses to the total number of requests; that is, the request-failure ratio.